# Render only when Context variable is not null REACT

Tags: reactjs, render, web-component

I am sure I am over complicating things, but I have a application that grabs user credentials at which point it performs a web auth to retrieve a sessionID. I take this session ID and save it in my App Context so that all the web components that need a sessionID can call the Context.

I am having a problem trying to figure out state in a manner that would allow me to wait for the SessionID to get populated before rendering the web components.

I have tried various conditional rendering techniques but apparently I am an idiot haha.

````js
import React from "react";
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import './FetchEndpoints.css'
import { AppContext } from "../../context/AppContext";


export default class FetchEndpoints extends React.Component {

  static contextType = AppContext

  state = {
    loading: true,
    dreturn: null,
    render: false
  };

   async componentDidMount(){
      const {session} = this.context
      const url = "https://portal.local";
      let headers = new Headers();
      process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
      headers.set('session', session);
      console.log(session)
      const response = await fetch(url,{method:'POST',
          headers: headers
         });
      const r_data = await response.json();;
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        chartData : {
        datasets:[
          {
            label: 'Endpoints',
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
                'rgba(54,162,235,0.2)',
                'rgba(255,206,86,0.2)',
                'rgba(75,192,192,0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            data: [r_data.info.data.total, r_data.info.data.unmanaged,r_data.info.data.managed,r_data.info.data.unmanageable]
          }
        ]
       }
      })

    }

  render() {

    if (this.state.loading) {
     return( <h1>...loading</h1>)
    }

    return (
      <Draggable
      handle=".handle"
      defaultPosition={{x: 0, y: 0}}
      position={null}
      grid={[25, 25]}
      scale={1}
      onStart={this.handleStart}
      onDrag={this.handleDrag}
      onStop={this.handleStop}>
        <div className="handle">
        <div>
        <div className="EndpointBox">
           <div className = 'chart'>
        <Bar
        data={this.state.chartData}
        width={600}
        height={200}
        options={{
           maintainAspectRatio: false,
           title: {
             display:true,
             text:'Discovered Interfaces',
             fontSize:15
           },
           legend:{
             display:false
           }
          }}
        />
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Draggable>

    );
  }
}```

The session from AppContext renders after the above has already ran. I would like to set something up so that it would if session is null wait for session to not be null.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably move the logic contained in `componentDidMount` to a separate function - `fetchCartData` for example.

Then, you could implement something like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    if(this.context.session !== null) {
        this.fetchChartData();
    };
}

async componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.context.session !== null) {
        this.fetchChartData();
    };
}
```

Comment: Pierre...If I could hug you I would. So that works amazing especially when I realized it wasn't context.session but context.data.session.

Comment: (づ｡◕‿‿◕｡)づ Thanks again